# how to prevent the security warning in Internet Explorer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ssl, cross-browser

I have a ruby on rails website with a security certificate installed for SSL. I don't get any kind of security warnings in other browsers such as Chrome or Firefox, but I get this in IE

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

If I select "No", everything displays just fine and the CSS files are accessed correctly. But how I can prevent this from popping up completely? I used StartSSL for the cert and the CSS files are part of non-secure if that helps.

Comment: You have 1+ HTTP requests coming over HTTP, not HTTPS (backed by an SSL connection). Put the link to your site here; someone can point out the request(s) making this alert show up.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is being caused by CSS files because when I only view secure items, none of the formatting is right. My question is - how can I make the CSS files that are inside the assets directory HTTPS friendly?

Comment: What more can I do but to tell you why you're getting the error and ask you for specific information so I can provide further help?

Comment: Reference your CSS files as "//www.domain.tld/path/to.css" and not "http://www.domain.tld/path/to.css". This will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your page, you are specifying a file with a URL that starts `http://`, where the URL for the main page starts with `https://`.

`https` is intended for secure sites, but having any non `https` content on the same page compromises that security. This is what IE is warning you about.

You need to ensure that all elements in the page are downloaded via a `https://` URL.

If you're not sure which files are being downloaded with the wrong protocol, you could use IE's Dev Tools window to view the page traffic. Open the Dev Tools by pressing F12, then load the page (answer 'Yes' to the security question so you can be sure everything is downloaded). You should be able to see all the files that were loaded to open the page, and should be able to see from that which one(s) are loaded via `http://` instead of `https://`. Those are the ones you need to fix.

Hope that helps